# how to evaluate if an update is necessary?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

hello all forum colleagues
I have a doubt why there are updates to be made IN THE TERMINAL that are not in the USN?

this update is not in the usn last similar was many months ago

example recently an update appeared that is not in the usn and is normal where I can follow if the update I'm doing is necessary
thanks

```
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto                                                                                                                                                          
Calculando atualização... Pronto                                                                                                                                                              
Os pacotes a seguir serão mantidos em suas versões atuais:                                                                                                                                    
  cryptsetup cryptsetup-bin cryptsetup-initramfs libcryptsetup12
```

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=&details=cryptsetup

https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?offset=10

Comment: Your linked resource tells you how to report a security vulnerability in an Ubuntu package. This is not the place to do it. Go to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/FAQ#Contact if you any concerns.

Comment: Only security updates are listed in USN. Non-security updates are NOT listed in USN. `cryptesetup`, for example, recently issued a non-security update ([changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/c/cryptsetup/cryptsetup_2.4.3-1ubuntu1.1/changelog))

Comment: thanks for your attention I feel confused about this topic I will read the link you sent me thank you